# Hover on button does not work on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

I've coded some buttons that increase in size when hovered.
It works perfectly on Chrome, yet on Firefox it doesn't do anything.

What's going wrong?

```css
.P1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 110px;
}
.roundB {
  height: 60%;
  width: 80%;
}
.roundB:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 115%;
}
```

```html
<div class="span12 buttonLoc">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="P1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <img src="../imgs/P1.png" class="roundB" title="Meet Sir Workalot" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="P1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
      <img src="../imgs/P2.png" class="roundB" title="Meet Cory" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="P1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
      <img src="../imgs/P3.png" class="roundB" title="Meet Azure" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="P1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">
      <img src="../imgs/P4.png" class="roundB" title="Meet Patonaldo" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="P1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4">
      <img src="../imgs/P5.png" class="roundB" title="Meet Buggy" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="P1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">
      <img src="../imgs/P6.png" class="roundB" title="Meet the Zebras" />
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think it's the way how firefox rendering data , try to replace  button with div maybe it's worked

Comment: Possibly a Firefox bug: [Bug 843003 - Children of button does not respond to :hover](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003)

Comment: Woow, mohade, that was it! It needs some adjustments but it works just fine. I would've never guessed that, thanks a lot :D

Comment: I guess `<button>` should not have children, just as `<input type='button' />` does not. Notice the later is self-closing.

Comment: you are very welcome MR A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is only accept hover on button (not see elements inside button tag). If You replace selector `.roundB:hover` to `.P1:hover .roundB` this will works the same like now on chrome.

Comment: Ok definetly your answer is the best. It works 100%, and I don't need to do any adjustments if I use your tip.

Thanks a lot for your time and help :)