# A button is working, but just not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using a clickable html button that should show a bunch of white words against an orange background. When hovered over, the orange turns into blue.

However, in Firefox, the white lettering disappears, leaving an orange block. The lettering shows up when hovered over, but it should be visible.

Help! I am a newbie who purchased this template but can't get it to work.

Here's the html and css for my page at http://plus.mytimedesign.com/index2017.html

```
<a class="cta-btn" data-lead-id="cta-btn" href="index2017details.html">Click Here for Further Program Details</a>
```

-------------CSS below--------------

```
.cta-btn {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fffffe;
    background: #f69f1b;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.cta-btn:link {
    color: #fffffe;
}

.cta-btn:hover {
    color: #fffffd;
    background: #1099c6;
}

.cta-link {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 550px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.cta-link:link,
.cta-link:visited {
    color: #222222;
}

.cta-link:hover {
    color: #f69f1b;
}

.cta-link__img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 104px;
    width: 104px;
    max-width: 104px;
}

.cta-link__text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Francis

Comment: Can’t reproduce; looks the same to me (including hover state) in bot a current Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hmm... I am using Windows 7 but a colleague's Windows 8.1 Firefox shows the same error... Curious. Tx for the quick response, BTW.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either...what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Version 53.0.3 - it claims to be up to date...

Comment: Would this be related to this problem, I wonder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758704/hover-on-button-does-not-work-on-firefox?rq=1

Comment: This problem is really a strange one. When I tested Firefox on Turbo.net Sandbox, it looks fine on their version of Firefox. However, the same version installed on my machine (and my colleague's) shows the error. I'm giving up on this... it seems that the problem is rare and I can't find the source. If it happens, it appears to be rare enough to overlook for the intended purpose.